# Configure Wildfly dependencies on IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, wildfly

With Eclipse, there is a JBoss plugin that will add the Wildfly Runtime to the project.
With IntelliJ, my code won't compile because it can't find the correct jars.

For exemple `import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;` won't compile.

I have tried to add the maven dependency Bill Of Material, but IntelliJ doesn't import jars (`org.wildfly.bom:jboss-javaee-7.0-wildfly:9.0.1.Final`)